# Is it possible to configure RubyMine to use double quotes in intentions?

Tags: rubymine

When I use the intention to convert a symbol to a string in RubyMine, it uses single quotes. Is it possible to configure RubyMine to use double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible right now, [vote for the related issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-8101) or [submit a new one](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RUBY).